# Why I cant access the texts of the hidden columns in this DataTable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

**The problem**

I have adatatable and I am trying to access the text of each cell in each row in order to print the texts and display all elements including the hidden ones.

**The Code to access the database**

```
     $("#myTable").on("click", ".edit_admin", function(e) {
                const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
                window.rowindex = $row;                
                const admin_phone = $row.find(".admin_phone").text().trim();
                const admin_email = $row.find(".admin_email").text().trim();
                const admin_location_name = $row.find(".admin_location_name").text().trim();
                const admin_location_id = $row.find(".admin_location_id").text().trim(); //hidden column
                const admin_id = $row.find(".admin_id").text().trim(); //hidden column
     });
```

**Information on problem**

All of the other elements are accessible and I can print their texts but it doesn't display anything from the hidden ones, why?

**I am hiding them when I initialize the DataTable:**

```
    ...
     {
       "targets": [3,4],
       "visible": false
     }
    ...
```

**The Question**

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colum-header` to use hidden value from your `DataTable` like below.

```
$("#myTable").on("click", ".edit_admin", function(e) {
  const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
  const data = $('#myTable').DataTable().row($row).data();
  const admin_phone = data['colum-header']; // May be this is phone-number which is not shown in your code
  //hidden column
  const admin_id = data['colum-header-id']; // May be column header is ID , it's not shown in your code
});
```